# Resampling 15 minute data to 1 minute without aggregation

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have attached the example of a dataframe which is based quarterly. I wish to resample it to per minute without any aggregation

Input dataframe:

| Date (CET) | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 11:00 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:15 | 60 |
| 2020-01-01 11:15 | 100 |

The output I want is this:

| Date (CET) | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 11:00 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:01 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:02 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:03 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:04 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:05 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:06 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:07 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:08 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:09 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:10 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:11 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:12 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:13 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:14 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 11:15 | 60 |

I tried using `df.resample`, but it requires me to aggregated based on the `mean()` or `sum()`, which I don't want. I want the values to remain the same for a particular quarter. Like in the output table the price remains 50 from `11:00` to `11:14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert to DatetimeIndex
df['Date (CET)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date (CET)'])

#remove duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates('Date (CET)')

df = df.set_index('Date (CET)')

#forward filling values - upsample
df.resample('Min').ffill()
```

Comment: Thanks. But i get this error `ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
`

Comment: @Cloude - added row to sample data in Qestion

Comment: I got an error because I had duplicate values. This is due to day-light saving, one hour is repeated. After using `df.drop_duplicates` your code worked. Thanks. I can add the missing hour manually maybe

Comment: @Cloude - It depends what need.

Comment: I do need that extra hour in the dataset, but since `df.resample` requires no duplicates I cannot. Please let know if you any suggestion for that

Comment: @Cloude - Can you be more specific and add this problematic data to question and add expected ouput?